# Nextcord - Nextcord.client - INFO - Got a request to RESUME the websocket

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I use Python with the Discord library called Nextcord.py

I have this INFO when building my discord bot...I wanna know if it's a problem from my bot or a warning. If it is possible, how to remove it ?

[image]

Comment: That's not a problem at all. Check the file where you set up your logging and set it to a higher level if you want to ignore `INFO` (Can be set to `WARNING` only for example)